# FileMaker Pro and Onedrive

Tags: database, odbc, integration, onedrive, filemaker

I have been tasked with a unique filemaker pro problem and was hoping I could get help with. My company wants to place an excel file on onedrive and for that file to connect to a FM database, meaning when the excel is edited, the database is updated/edited, is this possible?

Comment: I believe it's possible, but it won't be simple - esp. if you want the change to trigger the update in FM (as opposed to a periodical check, as proposed below). I suspect there may be a simpler solution to the real problem that this is attempting to solve, and of which you haven't told us anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. You can use Microsoft's API to read the file on OneDrive and reimport it into a FileMaker table if it changed.

This can be done with a FileMaker server schedule, running as frequently as you want. (Every 20 minutes?)

Comment: Would this require webhooks and a webserver? Or can I use FileMaker Server?

Comment: @rawdata this approach does not require webhooks or a webserver, just a FileMaker Server "schedule" and a script that uses Microsoft's "Graph API" to talk to OneDrive. You can probably use a tool like Zapier to talk to OneDrive if you don't want to write the API integration code yourself.

Comment: BTW, I agree with the answer above that there may be an alternative workflow that saves you a lot of coding.

Comment: thanks again for your reply. I have never created/worked Graph API. I would sincerely appreciate if you could walk me through the steps I need to take. First create the Graph API that reads the excel and then how do I point it to the specific database?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DBServices sample file here: https://dbservices.com/blog/filemaker-onedrive-integration

This covers everything from Creating a folder, uploading & downloading files from OneDrive!

The rest is pretty much scripting to compare files / timestamps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).